# Passive voice of “they did not do the work”

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

What is the passive voice of “they did not do the work”?

Comment: I cleared the close votes on this question because even though it does not meet our quality standards, closing it would reject the migration and remove answers that would potentially be useful to other learners. You should take a look at [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161) link on [meta]. There are some [examples of questions with good detail](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4584/9161) in an answer to that post. It helps us write better answers if we understand what you already know and what you've tried to do to answer your question before you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such a sentence one is " Dummy Do", the meaningless one the support of which we seek in Simple Present and Simple past where there is no auxiliary or modal but the sentence is to be made negative or interrogative.

Ignore this first DO, the meaningless one, we call do support.

- They ( did) NOT DO the work.

We know 'do support' embodies the tense and person of the finite verb. Thus deduced, the sentence is in simple past.

Let's make it passive.

- The work was not done by them.

We know BE Verb in a sentence is conspicuous by its presence in the sense that it precedes the subject in questions and turns negative all by itself without support of any helping verb, irrespective of the fact that BE VERB is there either as a  main verb or as an auxiliary.

Answer (score 13):

The work was not done by them.

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer, for example to explain *why* this is passive voice. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely:

> The work wasn't done (by them).

We form the passive using the auxiliary "to be" + past participle. "by them" is optional since we usually focus on the action when we use the passive.

Comment: We form the passive using the auxiliary     "to be" + "past pariticiple".  (by them) is optional since we usually focus on the action when we use the passive.

Comment: This should go in the answer :) You can edit and add your explanation.

Comment: The other critical step you did not mention in converting between active and passive voice is swapping the subject and object of the verb.

Comment: @Mossaab Cherai I have serious reservation to call the " to be " we use in passive voice an auxiliary; it is to my mind is THE MAIN VERB. : Follow its use in tense formation.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "they did not do the work" and "the work was not done by them" is the latter does not convey that the work was not done, and implies someone else may have.  The question that follows is "well who did it?"

I prefer a more specific choice of words to more clearly create the inference that *the work was not done at all*:

> the work was overlooked (by them).

Comment: The OP asks about passive voice This is a purely grammatical question.

Comment: @TonyK my apologies, I erred in claiming my statement was active voice.  Edited.